# Anyone using IronJS yet?

Tags: javascript, dynamic-language-runtime, ironjs

I'm just wondering if there is anyone else using [IronJS](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS) within their apps yet?

IronJS is really awesome as it's JavaScript on the DLR. Personally, I've been waiting to be able to write both server-side and client-side code in ASP.NET / ASP.NET MVC using JavaScript. It's too bad Microsoft abandoned Managed JScript, but no worries since IronJS is really showing promise.

I am wondering if anyone has started using it in any of their apps yet?

Lately, I've been playing around a little bit with adding the ability to code ASP.NET MVC Controller Actions in JavaScript using IronJS.

Comment: Had exactly same idea :) - very interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a developer on the IronJS, I have to say that I am using it. :)

However, most of my work has been running command-line projects like CoffeeScript (which works, 100%) and Uglify.js (which is not quite working).

If you find any rough edges, please post them on the GitHub bug tracker.  I will also be watching the IronJS tag here on SO, to help with any Q/A style requests.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with integrating ASP.NET MVC and IronJS, and the result is the new [IronJSMVC](https://github.com/crpietschmann/IronJSMVC) project. If you are interested in IronJS, then you'll probably be interested in IronJSMVC.

https://github.com/crpietschmann/IronJSMVC

It's still in a very early prototype stage (at the time of posting this) and not meant for production use just yet. But don't let that scare you away from checking it out.

Comment: Is it possible to write controllers & some of node's existing JavaScript templating?

Answer (score 0):

I actually played a bit with in my DynamicPad project
https://github.com/khebbie/Dynamicpad/

But decided on using IronRuby since it's more mature

By the way I also had some fun playing with IronJs in linqPad
https://gist.github.com/1256505